# Flutter ListView exception with unbounded height

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing a new Flutter app on Android Studio. One page of my app gets the information from a `Future`. With the future's result I'm creating a `ListView.builder()`:

Here's the code:

```
Widget encabezados(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
  {
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Card(
          elevation: 3,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 0.0,),
              Category(
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                val: clientesacobrar.toString(),
                title: "Clientes a cobrar",
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
              Category(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                title: "Clientes cobrados",
                val: clientescobrados.toString(),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
              Category(
                val: formatter.format(montoacobrar),
                //val: records.length.toString(),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                title: "Monto a cobrar",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        new ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

          //elevation: 3,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(

                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  //ShrinkWrappingViewport: true,
                  itemCount: records.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return records.isNotEmpty
                        ? Card(
                        child: Padding (
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.00),
                          child: Text(records[index].nombre),
                        )
                    )
                        : CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
              )
            ],
        )
      ],
    );


  }
```

As you can see in the listviews widgets I'm using `shrinkWrap` set to `true`, because if I don't set this I get:

```
I/flutter (22634): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (22634): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter (22634): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter (22634): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter (22634): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter (22634): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter (22634): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter (22634): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter (22634): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

But if I set the `shrinkwrap` property I'm not able to scroll the page on my app

I have tried putting the `ListView.builder()` into:
container widget , column widget, `ListView` widget but in the `ListView.builder()` I'm always asked to set the `shrinkwrap` property.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to constrain your parent widget so it knows where the bounds are.

For that scenario, wrapping in a `Container` alone, won’t have any effect unless you explicit constrain it (eg. by setting  constrains or just giving it a explicit height).

```
Container(
    height: 200.0, // or whatever
    child: ListView(
  ....
  )
)
```

As an alternative, you can also set your inner `ListView` physics to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` which will prevent any scroll from happening in the inner one and only the top scroll view will control scroll.

If all of that doesn't help, you may need to use a `CustomScrollView` which lets you nest multiple scroll views, basically a `Sliver`.

Comment: what about a dynamic height? for handle listview inside listview?

Comment: You can either use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` physics for the inner one or a `CustomScrollView` which lets you nest scroll views.

Answer (score 18):

Try to add *physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()* to **inner** ListView.

Comment: @MichaelGabay , it should work if we wrap the listView inside SingleChildScrollView, in this case after adding physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() inside the listView, the scroll event will be handled by the SingleChildScrollView not by the listView

Answer (score 1):

[Miguel Ruivo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309664/3291390) is correct but rather than using a `Container` with an explicit height, you can instead wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` to give it the remaining height and allow it to scroll if needed.

**Note**: Make sure the [`Expanded widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) is a descendant of `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex`.

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
    ...
  )
)
```

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña It works, just make sure the `Expanded` widget is a child of `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex`. [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

Comment: I can confirm that this does in fact work. I had the same issue and it resolved my problem. Not sure why the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found out that the main thing is using the `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` property inside of your `ListView.Builder()` like so:

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      _buildHeader(),
      Container(
        // height: 40,
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // <= This was the key for me
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 1,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) {
            return _horizontalListView();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

I tested and It works with `Column`, `Container`, `Expanded` widgets as a parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

So something that seems odd is the fact that you have a whole heap of nested `ListView`'s. I suggest try limiting it to just one.

It's a little difficult to see what the intended outcome should be... Is the "Category card" meant to be static with the `ListView.builder` part scrolling underneath? Or does the "Category card" scroll with the content?

Either way, I think I've got something that you should be able to use. 
Included are ways of accomplishing either the static or scrolling head.

A note on the static header solution: I'm using a `Column` instead of a `ListView` This ensures we don't have top level scrolling going on. First child is your "header" with the second child the `ListView` responsible for the scrolling. This `ListView` is wrapped in `Expanded` to make sure the scrolling `ListView` takes up all of the remaining screen height.

Hope this helps

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SO Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sample Code'),
        ),
        body: _buildViewWithStaticCategories());
        // OR
    // body: _buildViewWithScrollingCategories());
  }

  Widget _buildViewWithStaticCategories() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildCategoriesCard(),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 20, // records.length
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.00),
                    child: Text(index.toString()),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildViewWithScrollingCategories() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 21, // records.length + 1 for the Categories card
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return index == 0
            ? _buildCategoriesCard()
            : Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.00),
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                ),
              );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategoriesCard() {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('one'), // Category( ...
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Text('two'), // Category( ...
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Text('three'), // Category( ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```